# SQL Concatenate Distinct Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have the following query where I am concatenating a list of products and quotes by account and version number.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST2.Account_No, ST2.version_num,
    substring((SELECT  ',' +  ST1.ProductNo  AS [text()]
            FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT Account_No, version_num, ProductNo, QuoteNo, RowNo
                    FROM uAccountProductInfo) ST1
            WHERE ST1.version_num = ST2.version_num  
                AND ST1.Account_No = ST2.Account_No  
            ORDER BY ST1.RowNo, ST1.Account_No,ST1.version_num
            FOR XML PATH (''))
    , 2, 1000) [AllProduct]
    ,
    substring((SELECT  ','+  ST3.QuoteNo  AS [text()]
            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Account_No, version_num, ProductNo, QuoteNo, RowNo
            FROM [uAccountProductInfo]) ST3
            WHERE ST3.version_num = ST2.version_num  
                AND ST3.Account_No = ST2.Account_No  
            ORDER BY ST3.RowNo, ST3.version_num 
            FOR XML PATH (''))
    , 2, 1000) [AllQuote]
FROM uAccountProductInfo ST2
```

The problem I am experiencing is that the return values are not showing the distinct results. I understand the reason it's happening but cannot figure out how to adjust it.

Return results look this:

```
Account    version_num     AllProduct    AllQuote    
1          2               aaa,aaa,aaa   111,111,111
1          3               aaa,aaa,bbb   111,111,222
```

What I want is

```
Account    version_num     AllProduct    AllQuote    
1          2               aaa,          111
1          3               aaa,bbb       111,222
```

Test Data would be this:

```
Account    version_num    LOB    Package    Product    Quote    RowNo
1          2              GL     1          aaa        111      1
1          2              AU     1          aaa        111      2    
1          2              PF     1          aaa        111      3
1          3              GL     1          aaa        111      1
1          3              AU     1          aaa        111      2
1          3              WK     0          bbb        222      3
```

The reason they are returning with multiple instances of the same product | quote is due to the inclusion of `RowNo` column. I had this excluded before which returned the distinct list of values, but I need to order by RowNo so that the values come in a specific order.

I have been wracking my brain all morning but cannot figure out how to adjust the query to only return the distinct values at the top level.

Any suggestions?

*n.b. - this is part of a larger query  but once this subquery is resolved it should flow into main one just fine (at least I think). I can post main query if people need.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I much prefer `stuff()` rather than `substring()` for removing the separating character.  What you require, though, is `select distinct` or `group by` *in the subquery*:

```
stuff((SELECT ',' +  ST1.ProductNo  AS [text()]
       FROM uAccountProductInfo ST1
       WHERE ST1.version_num = ST2.version_num AND
             ST1.Account_No = ST2.Account_No  
       GROUP BY ST1.ProductNo
       ORDER BY MIN(ST1.RowNo) 
       FOR XML PATH ('')
      ), 1, 1, '')
```

Your additional subquery is superfluous.  In fact, it is misleading because you are using `SELECT DISTINCT` and expect it to return one row per `ProductNo` -- even when multiple rows exist with different values in the other columns.

Note that the ordering is unclear.  This bases it on the minimum `RowNo`.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to be working very well :). I'll test more after lunch. The order you assumed is correct. I updated my test data in the OP for clarity. Thanks for the note in the superfluous subquery as well.

Comment: Curious why you prefer `stuff` over `substring` if you care to elaborate or link to a performance rational? (Thanks in advance).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman . . . Simply because the length parameter is not needed.